# Google maps Google logo

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a (documented) way to change the Google logo (not hide) in Google Maps API v3?

By default it uses:

[image: 1]

But I have seen implementations showing the map with this logo:

[image: 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A custom maptype will currently result in the white logo:

```
map.mapTypes.set('styledmap', new google.maps.StyledMapType(myStyledMap));
map.setMapTypeId('styledmap');
```

(as opposite to defining the styled map while constructing the map object)

Answer (score 1):

There is no API-option to change the logo.

The used  logo depends on the used maptype(e.g. for "satellite" you get the white logo )